# How far into the future can iOS local notifications be scheduled?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push-notification

If I'm scheduling a local notification in iOS how far into the future can I schedule it? Is there a limit? Will it be deleted if the phone dies or is updated? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit as far as the app is installed at that time.

I am assuming that you mean when battery dies when you say phone dies. Yes it would still be scheduled if your phone battery dies or it is updated as long as the app is there.